# If I open same file to debug on gdb... how come they have same register address?

Tags: assembly, gdb, reverse-engineering

for example the test file is ddd

```
>gdb -q ddd <- on one terminal
>gdb -q ddd <- on the other terminal
```

but when I disassemble it(while run)... how come it gives same register addresses [click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRyt0.jpg)

ps. I am english learner... if my english is not clear enough, sorry :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

Comment: it basically means that the functions/symbols inside your compiled object start with the same address, nothing that really depends on the single instruction .

Answer (score 0):

Unless the OS is using [ASLR](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18556/how-do-aslr-and-dep-work), the start addresses of segments remain the same as defined by the executable headers on different executions.